# Unicode string analyser with neatly arranged results

Tags: linux, open-source, unicode

I have a string and want to know of which Unicode characters it consists. Character name and code point is sufficient.

A solution must be FLOSS and run natively on GNU/Linux.

The command-line tool [`unicode`](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/unicode/) can do this, but the display of the results is not easy to parse visually, as the characters are displayed inbetween each character’s metadata block:

> [image: "Oh, hai" result of unicode]

The web app https://r12a.github.io/uniview/ has a better presentation, as you can read your original string (although vertical) next to the result, without having to skip metadata lines:

> [image: "Oh, hai" result of UniView]

Which tool has a better result presentation?

Ideally it would be a GUI where the input string is shown horizontally, non-visual characters get marked somehow, and clicking on a character shows its name and metadata. But I’m open for other solutions; I’d even be happy with an UniView-like display, if there is a local client using somethimg similar.

Answer (score 3):

You can get more or less what you need using python and its unicodedata module - something like:

```
import unicodedata as ucd
u = u'The UK uses £ but Japan ¥'
for c in u:
    print c, "%04x" % ord(c), ucd.category(c), ucd.name(c)
```

produces:

```
T 0054 Lu LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
h 0068 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER H
e 0065 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER E
  0020 Zs SPACE
U 0055 Lu LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
K 004b Lu LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
  0020 Zs SPACE
u 0075 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER U
s 0073 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER S
e 0065 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER E
s 0073 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER S
  0020 Zs SPACE
£ 00a3 Sc POUND SIGN
  0020 Zs SPACE
b 0062 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER B
u 0075 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER U
t 0074 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER T
  0020 Zs SPACE
J 004a Lu LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J
a 0061 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER A
p 0070 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER P
a 0061 Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER A
n 006e Ll LATIN SMALL LETTER N
  0020 Zs SPACE
¥ 00a5 Sc YEN SIGN
```

You could also output your input first and easily, (using sets), only output one line for each distinct character which might be even more use.

- Free
- Already installed on most Linux distros
- If you need a GUI, or html output, you could knock one up quite quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily change the presentation by piping the output of `unicode` into a bit of text rewriting. To get the same presentation as the UniView web app:

```
unicode -s 'Oh, hai' |
perl -000 -ne '/^U+(.*)\n.*\n(.)/ and print "$2 $1\n"'
```

Alternatively, you could type your text in an editor with good editor support. For example, in Emacs, press `C-u C-x =` (command [`what-cursor-position`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/International-Chars.html#International-Chars) with a prefix argument) to show a lot of information about the character under the cursor, including its Unicode code point, name and properties.